# Pass data between 2 React DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-dom

In a website, I have multiple react rendering elements. I want to pass the data between this 2 individual elements. What are the possible options for passing the data between 2 elements

```
ReactDOM.render(<Header/>, document.getElementById('header'));
ReactDOM.render(<SideBar/>, document.getElementById('sidebar'));
```

I want to have a single data storage between these elements. Like I get data in one component and I want that data to be accessible in all the elements (in all ReactDOM). 
So what can be the possible options for this?

Edit: Due to requirement I can't merge them in to same root component. Only some portion of page is in react other is still in the HTML/Jquery. So I render them individually in the required div.

Does redux store work between different ReactDOMs?

Comment: check this too: https://www.javascriptstuff.com/component-communication/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) from the `react-dom` library:

> Portals provide a first-class way to render children into a DOM node that exists outside the DOM hierarchy of the parent component.

---

```
const HeaderPortal = ReactDOM.createPortal(<Header />, document.getElementById('header'))
const SideBarPortal = ReactDOM.createPortal(<SideBar />, document.getElementById('sidebar'))

const store = createStore(/* ... */)

ReactDOM.render(
  <YourDataStoreProvider store={store}>
    <HeaderPortal />
    <SideBarPortal />
  </YourDataStoreProvider>, 
  document.getElementById('root') // assuming you have an empty "dummy" node with that id
);
```

Just render you app into a container anywhere in your DOM or create a new "dummy" node. In my example I assume there is an empty node with the id `root`. Then render your other components into a portal.

> Does redux store works between different ReactDOMs?

Your app will work as if it was rendered entirely into the same container. If you use Portals your components will be in the same component tree having the same context while being rendered somewhere else.

### Should I use Portals?

Using Portals usually is intended to be used for components that visually need to "break out" of its container like modals or dialogs. But you can also use them to create widget-like components that can be rendered anywhere.

### Creating a generic Portal component

You can also create a generic `<Portal>` component that creates a portal given a container `id`:

```
import {createPortal} from 'react-dom';

const Portal = ({children, container}) => createPortal(
    children,
    document.getElementById(container),
);

export default Portal;
```

And use it this way:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <YourDataStoreProvider store={store}>
    <Portal container="header">
      <Header />
    </Portal>
    <Portal container="sidebar">
      <SideBar />
    </Portal>
  </YourDataStoreProvider>, 
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**EDIT**:

You need one node in the DOM where you can render your app. This can be a new DOM element that you create or it can be one of the containers you already have. Given you use the `<Portal>` component from above it could also look like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <YourDataStoreProvider store={store}>
        <Header /> // this will be visible in your header container
        <Portal container="sidebar">
            <SideBar /> // this will be rendered to the sidebar container
        </Portal>
    </YourDataStoreProvider>, 
    document.getElementById('header')
);
```

This will render your app in the `header` container. But only your `<Header>` component will actually have a DOM representation in that container. The sidebar will be rendered in the `sidebar` container by the portal. But still they will share the same react component tree and have the same store provider.

Comment: Due to requirement i can't merge them in to same root component. Only some portion of page is in react other is still in the HTML/Jquery. So I render them individually in the required div. I will check for the Portals according to your description i should able to use it for the different DOMs

Comment: @hardiksa Then portals are a good way to solve this. The root element in my example is nothing that already needs to be there. You could just create a new node in the body and render your app there. In fact you could just use the header container as your root for the whole app and render everything else with portals. There just needs to be one node where you actually render the app with the store provider because you said you want a store that is accessible from all your components.

Comment: @hardiksa I updated my answer with an example that does not require a third DOM element to render the app.

Comment: Okay. so I can use a single render method to render each component in it's individual div. I only need to render one real component then I can add any number of component via portal and all of them will use the same provider but individual div elements in the real html, right?

Comment: @hardiksa Yes exactly. Technically you need one container that holds your app with the store provider due to how react works. It can be one of the containers you already have or you can create "dummy" container with `document.createElement()`. If you use an existing one you have to render all the components with portals that should not be inside that container. Your app will work as if they where rendered all in the same container.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a component container and have both as a child and render them separate. Exchange the data through props and the mother container.

I provide an example:

https://codepen.io/hkares/pen/rvLPzQ

HTML

```
//html
<header id="header"></header>
<main>
  <nav id="nav"></nav>
  <section>I am section</section>
</main>
<footer>This is a footer</footer>
<div id="useless"></div>
```

Index.js

```
const HEADER_NODE = document.querySelector("#header");
const NAVBAR_NODE = document.querySelector("#nav");

const Header = ({ name }) => ReactDOM.createPortal(<h1>{name}</h1>, HEADER_NODE);

const NavBar = (props) => ReactDOM.createPortal(
  <article>
    <label>
      Set header name: <input {...props} />
    </label>
  </article>
, NAVBAR_NODE);

class Container extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: "this is a header"
    };
  }

  onChange = ({ target }) => this.setState({ value: target.value });

  render() {
    const { value } = this.state;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Header name={value} />
        <NavBar value={value} onChange={this.onChange} />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Container />,
  document.querySelector("#useless")
);
```

Comment: Can you provide any code or reference like how can I render them as separate. I need to have render methods independent i can't combine them in one.Only some portion of page is in react other is still in the HTML/Jquery. So I render them individually.

Answer (score 0):

container component

```
    class App extends React.Component{


    render(){
var data=[];
    return(<span>
     <Header data={data}/>
        <SideBar data={data}/>
        </span>);
    }

}
```

Comment: Due to requirement i can't merge them in to same component. Only some portion of page is in react other is still in the HTML/Jquery. So I render them individually in the required divs.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the relationship between the two components.

**Scenario I**:If they are just siblings, then you can wrap them in your container component or just a simple , and passing the props to the child, like

```
<div>
   <HeaderPortal data={yourSharedData}/>
   <SideBarPortal data={yourSharedData}/>
</div>
```

or

```
   <YourContainer>
       <HeaderPortal />
       <SideBarPortal/>
   </YourContainer>
```

Then in `YourContainer`, you can define your shared data, and add them to each of your child like

```
render(){
   <div>
     {children.map(child=> React.cloneElement(child, {
         data: yourSharedData
      })}
   </div>
}
```

**Scenario II** If these two components are far from each other
[image]
Like the above, you wanna share data between 2 and 12, then you should use `redux` storage to share the data, which is a central places to manage your component state, and share any part it to the required component via `mapStateToProps`, you can find more details [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux).

Comment: Due to requirement i can't merge them in to same component. Only some portion of page is in react other is still in the HTML/Jquery. So I render them individually in the required div.

Answer (score 0):

Build a context system：

- a context is an object that stores data.
- a module can access and update data in context.
- a module can be notified when data in context is updated.
- depends on your need, a module can either freely add data to context, or restrict to only update existing data.

It's not really a react specific problem.

An example of context system look like this:

**content.js**

```
import uniqueId from 'lodash/uniqueId';

let context = {
  foo: '',
  bar: ''
};

let listeners = {
  // key: [{ id, callback }]
};

let getAppContext = function(key) {
  return context[key];
};

let updateAppContext = function(key, value) {
  if (!context.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    throw new Error(
      `Failed to update appContenxt: "${key}" does not exist.`
    );
  }

  let oldValue = context[key];
  context[key] = value;
  let callbacks = listeners[key];
  if (callbacks !== undefined && callbacks.length !== 0) {
    callbacks.forEach(function(item) {
      item.callback(value, oldValue);
    });
  }
};

let onAppContextUpdate = function(key, callback) {
  if (!context.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    throw new Error(
      `Failed to add listener on appContenxt update: "${key}" does not exist.`
    );
  }

  if (listeners[key] === undefined) {
    listeners[key] = [];
  }

  let isListening = true;
  let id = uniqueId();
  listeners[key].push({ id, callback });

  return function removeListener() {
    if (isListening) {
      listeners[key] = listeners[key].filter(i => i.id !== id);
      isListening = false;
    }
  };
};

export {
  getAppContext,
  updateAppContext,
  onAppContextUpdate,
};
```

**Usage**

```
import { getAppContext, updateAppContext, onAppContextUpdate } from 'content.js';

// read foo
let foo = getAppContext('foo');

// update foo
updateAppContext('foo', 123);

// get notified when foo is updated
let removeListener = onAppContextUpdate('foo', function(newVal, oldVal) {
  console.log(newVal, oldVal);
});

// unlisten
removeListener();
```